# scripts not loading

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

this is the header section for enqueueing my scripts

```
<?php 
wp_enqueue_script( 'menu' );
wp_enqueue_script('thumbnail');
?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"  type="text/css"  />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/menu-effect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/thumbnail-effect.js"></script>
</head>
```

and this is functions.php section

```
function my_jsfile() {
wp_register_script( 'menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu-effect.js', array() );
wp_register_script( 'thumbnail', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/thumbnail-effect.js', array() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jsfile' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enqueue scripts in `functions.php` itself with `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. Like this.

```
function my_jsfile() {

  wp_register_script( 'menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu-effect.js', array() );
  wp_register_script( 'thumbnail', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/thumbnail-effect.js', array() );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'menu' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'thumbnail' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jsfile' );
```

And also you should remove `wp_enqueue_script` from `header.php` as well as script links.

And finally make sure your script paths are correct.

Comment: still not working..i suppose its something in the header which is causing problem..

Comment: Did you remove `wp_enqueue_script` from `header.php`? And made sure path of these JS files are correct.

Comment: yes ..i removed script codes from header.php
and the paths are correct as well..

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_scripts` fires after the call to the function `wp_head()`. So your `wp_enqueue_script()` calls are too early.

**Register** your scripts on `wp_loaded`, **enqueue** them on `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
    $base = get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_register_script( 'menu',      "$base/js/menu-effect.js" );
    wp_register_script( 'thumbnail', "$base/js/thumbnail-effect.js" );
});


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'menu' );
    wp_enqueue_script('thumbnail');
});
```

Comment: nopes...not working

Comment: Enable the [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see why.